# Using a Conditional to populate a variable SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am coming from MySQL now working in SQL Server, writing a stored procedure that needs to set a value in the "like" clause based on the value in the Description column. Not sure if I should declare a variable (@desc) and then set it somehow of if there is an easier way?

**Pseudo-code:**

```
DECLARE @desc varchar(255);
IF [Description] LIKE '%KK%'
    SET @desc = 'KDues';
ELSE
    SET @desc = 'BDues';
```

**The actual query**

```
    SELECT
    Description,AmountDue
    [...]
    WHERE order_date BETWEEN @fiscalYearBeginDate AND @fiscalYearEndDate
    AND [Description] LIKE '%'+@desc+'%'
```

What's the best way to approach this? NOt sure how to use IF/ELSE or CASE in this particular scenario. Thanks

Comment: what?, I don't understand, sorry. It seems like you want to assign a value to `@desc` depending on a value from `[description]` and then use that value to filter a table using `LIKE` on that same column?

Comment: yes, that's right so i would probably need to join on itself. i think instead i will add another param that tells me what type i have up front and then set @desc accordingly

Comment: That's what I meant with clarifying your goal. How are you assigning the value for `@desc`?, is it even necessary to do that?. Can you post a sample data and a desired output?, that may be the easiest way to make your point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT Description, AmountDue
[...]
WHERE order_date BETWEEN @fiscalYearBeginDate AND @fiscalYearEndDate and
      Description like (case when Description LIKE '%KK%' then '%KDues%' else '%BDues%' end)
```

However, that is ugly.  You can eliminate the `case` using logic:

```
WHERE order_date BETWEEN @fiscalYearBeginDate AND @fiscalYearEndDate and
      ((Description like '%KK%' and Description like '%KDues%') or
        (Description not like '%KK%' and Description like '%BDues%')
      )
```

By the way, both of these forms are the same in MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: thanks but why are both likes in the first line containing '%KK%'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
case when Description like '%KK%'
then 'KDues'
ELSE
'BDues' end as Description ,AmountDue
[...]
WHERE order_date BETWEEN @fiscalYearBeginDate AND @fiscalYearEndDate
```